# QML plugin with static build

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have Qt compiled static, but when I run my application I get this error:

```
qrc:/files/particles/particles.qml:2:1: module "QtQuick.Particles" plugin "particlesplugin" not found 
     import QtQuick.Particles 2.0 
     ^
```

My imports related to QML are these:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0
```

I tried to follow the documentation:

```cpp
#include <QtPlugin>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);     
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQuick2Plugin)
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin) // <--- cause error
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQmlMetaPlugin)
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQmlPlugin)
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQmlModelsPlugin)
    Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQmlWorkerScriptPlugin)
```

But I'm getting this compilation error:

```cpp
1>main.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "struct QStaticPlugin const __cdecl qt_static_plugin_QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin(void)" (?qt_static_plugin_QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin@@YA?BUQStaticPlugin@@XZ) referenced in function main
```

I searched the source for proper way to import this plugin and I have found it at **C:\Qt\6.6.0_static\qtdeclarative\src\particles**

in the file **particlesplugin_init.cpp**:

```cpp
#include <QtPlugin>
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin)
```

Why is the compilation throwing that error?

I'm compiling using **Visual Studio 2022**.

I tested adding `#pragma comment(lib, "particlesplugin.lib")` into the `int main...` code above

and the compiler complained about not finding the lib.

I have them added to my project properties:

```
C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories -> C:\Qt\6.6.0_static\qml\QtQuick\Particles

Linker -> Input -> particlesplugin.lib
```

When recompiled, now I'm getting a different error:

```cpp
1>particlesplugin.lib(particlesplugin_QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin.cpp.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl qml_register_types_QtQuick_Particles(void)" (?qml_register_types_QtQuick_Particles@@YAXXZ) referenced in function "public: static __cdecl `public: static void (__cdecl*__cdecl QtPrivate::QMetaTypeForType<class QtQuick2ParticlesPlugin>::getDefaultCtr(void))(class QtPrivate::QMetaTypeInterface const *,void *)'::`5'::<lambda_1>::<lambda_invoker_cdecl>(class QtPrivate::QMetaTypeInterface const *,void *)" (?<lambda_invoker_cdecl>@<lambda_1>@?4??getDefaultCtr@?$QMetaTypeForType@VQtQuick2ParticlesPlugin@@@QtPrivate@@SAP6AXPEBVQMetaTypeInterface@4@PEAX@ZXZ@SA@01@Z)
```

I also get this external symbol error for **every** other **QtQuick** plugin that I try to import using `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN` and not only the **particlesplugin**.

I can't find anything about this in the documentation, what's going on?

Comment: I don't have a clear answer since my experience with QML is basically using my own Qt build (static), and CMake rather than VS; but AFAIU your question yes, you'd need to build the static version of Qt. Nevertheless, be careful not violating Qt's license when doing so: If I remember correctly, static linkage falls down to GPL unless you have a commercial license.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is a bug, follow the bugreport:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTVSADDINBUG-1173

> Qt/MSBuild is not providing all the necessary link dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I have also suffered from this issue but i found the right way to do it.
First you need to find the correct name of your plugin in the source code:
for example: quickparticlesystem is the file class name. You can use this website to find it : https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtdeclarative/src/particles/qquickparticlesystem.cpp.html

After this you should apply the camelCase:
quickParticleSystem
And the add Q at the first place and Plugin at the end:
QQuickParticleSystemPlugin

So if you do Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QQuickParticleSystemPlugin) it should work.

If you use CMake don't forget to use qt_import_plugins to import this plugin.

When i said i had the same issue is because i wanted to import linuxfb and others as a plugin. I have resolved this issue by adding :
Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried `Q_IMPORT_PLUGIN(QQuickParticleSystemPlugin)` but I continue getting the same error. Im using Visual Studio not CMake, i think the build of these static plugins is probably broken for VS